# Proof of Turan's theorem by induction

Tags: combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

I am reading the proof of Turan's theorem on $ex(n,K_r)$ in Diestel's Graph Theory book as follows.

Question: I am confused about the induction. The normal induction is that we first verify that $n=1$ is true. Assume that $n=k$ is true and verity $n=k+1$ is also true. However, in this proof we have known that $n\le r-1$ is true. What is the assumption here? Do we assume that $n=r$ is true? I am confused about the sentence

> By the induction hypothesis, $G-K^{r-1}$ has at most $t_{r-1}(n-r+1)$ edges?

[image]

Comment: It is similar. When we are doing induction for positive integers. We start from $r=1$. Then at this point, we have it holds for $r =1$, which is equivalent to $r \leq 1$. Then we do one-step induction to get $r = 2$, then at this point we not only have $r = 2$ but also have $r \leq 2$.

Comment: @VezenBU But what is the assumption? Do we assume that $n\le r$ is true? But why the author proves $n\ge r$ holds? I mean that Step 1: check $n\le r-1$ is true. Step 2: Assume that $n=r$ is true. Then verify $n\ge r+1$ holds?

Comment: It's like. (1) Check $n = 1$ is true; (2) Assume that $n \leq r - 1$ is true; (3) Verify that $n = r$ is true.

Comment: @VezenBU But if I understand right, the case for $n\le r-1$ is always true. We do not need to assume that.

Comment: Ah. I should not use $r$. It should be (1) Check $n=1$ is true; (2) Assume that $n \leq k−1$ is true; (3) Verify that $n=k$ is true. And in the proof we are seeing the case for $k = r$.

Comment: @VezenBU What does this sentence "in in the proof we are seeing the case for k=r" mean? In this proof, does the author check $n=1$ is true and assume $n\le r-1$ is true? For $n\le r-1$, the statement holds and we do not need to assume...

Comment: @VezenBU But the author check $n\ge r$ but not $n=r$. So what case does the author assume? I am so confused...

Comment: Okay, my question is why by the induction hypothesis, $G−K^{r−1}$ has at most $t_{r−1}(n−r+1)$ edges?

Comment: Because $G - K$ has at most $n - r + 1$ vertices

Comment: @VezenBU Why this result follows from the induction? Do we assume that every graph $G$ with $n-r+1$ vertices and $ex(n-r+1, K^r)$ edges is a $T^{n-r+1}(n)$? I am not sure about the assumption.

Comment: @VezenBU Do you mean $G-K$ should be a $T^{r-1}(n-r+1)$ graph? So its edges are at most $t_{r-1}(n-r+1)$?